How can two pitchers be credited with the same earned runs?
In the April 4, 2024 game MIA@STL, the final score was MIA 5 - STL 8. Looking at the box score, I see that two Miami pitchers combined to pitch the bottom of the seventh inning (Sanchez with one out and Nardi with 2 outs).  Both are credited with 2 ER.  However, the total ER for the game lists 3 (one ER on the starting pitcher). How can two pitchers be credited with the same 2 earned runs?

The earned runs for the pitchers are all different.   But of those 4 runs, only 2 are counted as earned for the team.



Batter
Order
Sanchez
Nardi
Miami




Goldschmidt
B2
unearned

unearned


Arenado
B3
Earned

Earned


Herrera
B4
Earned

Earned


Gorman
B5

Earned
unearned


Burleson
B7

Earned
unearned



When there are errors in an inning and runners score that "would not" have scored if the error had not occurred, those runs will be counted as unearned against the team.
But, if a pitcher enters in the middle of an inning after such an error, they don't personally get the benefit of those errors.   Assuming no more errors happen in the inning, all of a relief pitcher's runs would count as earned for that pitcher, and that's what happens here.
Sanchez starts the seventh and gets an out and an error, but B3 and B4 hit safely.
Nardi comes in to relieve.   By 9.16(i), his runs will ignore the previous error.
B5 hits, scoring B3 and B4: 2ER for Sanchez and 2ER for the team.
B6 flies out.   At that point with 2 out and one "should have been out", any further scoring will not be earned for the team.
B5 and B7 later score, being unearned runs for the team, but earned runs for Nardi.
This is discussed in the rules under a comment for 9.16(i):

Rule 9.16(i) Comment: It is the intent of Rule 9.16(i) to charge
a relief pitcher with earned runs for which such relief pitcher is
solely responsible. In some instances, runs charged as earned
against the relief pitcher can be charged as unearned against the
team. For example:

With two out and Peter pitching, Abel reaches first
base on a base on balls. Baker reaches first base on
an error. Roger relieves Peter. Charlie hits a home
run, scoring three runs. The Official Scorer shall
charge two unearned runs to Peter, one earned run to
Roger and three unearned runs to the team (because
the inning should have ended with the third out when
Baker batted and an error was committed).

... other examples omitted

